# How to format Yup date() to brazilian format?

Tags: yup

I'm wanting to use yup to validate an input, that is being used as Birthday. By first I added the simple .date() function to the yup shaped object, but it won't accept Brazilian dates, as the format is same as European (dd/MM/YYYY), how do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.transform()` to parse your value with a function passing the following parameters:

- `value` as current Date parsed by yup.
- `originalValue` as the original inputted value (e.g. "01/01/2022").

```js
yup.date().transform((value, originalValue) => {
   // Do your parsing structure
   return newValue
})
```

Remember that your `newValue` must be a `Date` object since you want to validate a `yup.date()` type in your form.

You can use this example as solution for you to parse your value to "dd/MM/YYYY" format:

```js
// Input: '10/12/2022'

// yup.object({ [...]
birthday: yup.date().transform((value, originalValue) => {
   // originalValue = "10/12/2022"
   try {
      let date = originalValue.split('/')
      // date = ["10", "12", "2022"] <- day, month and year respectively

      if (date.length === 3) {
         let newDate = `${date[2]}-${date[1]}-${date[0]}`
         return new Date(newDate)
      }
      return null
   } catch (e) {
      return null
   }
}),
// [...] })

// Expected Output: '2022-10-12T00:00:00.000Z'
```

> See yup docs about parsing values using `.transform()`: [Yup Schema Basics - Parsing: Transforms](https://github.com/jquense/yup#parsing-transforms)